# Portion of label bold - the rest not bold

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I'm using `d3.js` and the following snippet renders labels around a pie chart:

```
text.enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .style("opacity", 0.01)
    .text(function(d) {
        return (d.data.NAME + ": " + d.data.amount);
    });
```

So a label might read `Jimmy: 100`

How do I make `d.data.NAME` render in a bold style but `d.data.amount` should not be bold ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One solution is using a `<tspan>` element with a different `font-weight` for your `d.data.amount`.

Check the demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var text = svg.append("text")
  .attr("x", 10)
  .attr("y", 30)
  .attr("font-weight", 700)
  .text("This is bold...")
  .append("tspan")
  .attr("font-weight", 300)
  .text(" but this is not.")
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

In your case, it should be something like this:

```
//...
.style("font-weight", 700)
.text(function(d) {
    return d.data.NAME + ": ";
})
.append("tspan")
.style("font-weight", 300)
.text(function(d) {
    return d.data.amount;
});
```

Comment: ok - I can see it works but building it into the following transition I'm finding a challenge - let me create a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44547919/text-with-tspan-of-a-different-font-weight-within-a-complex-transition