# Text with tspan of a different font-weight within a complex transition

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So I've implemented the following excellent suggestion by Gerardo but then the following transition negates the two different font weights and they both end up bold

Previous post: 
[Portion of label bold - the rest not bold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44546656/portion-of-label-bold-the-rest-not-bold)

Code

```
text.enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .style("opacity", 0.01)
    .style("font-weight", 700)
    .text(function(d) {
        return (d.data.NAME + ": ");
    })
    .append("tspan")
    .style("font-weight", 200)
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.data.amount;
    });


text
    .transition()
    .duration(1400)
    .style("opacity", 1)
    .style("font-weight", 700)
    .attrTween("transform", function(d) {
        this._current = this._current || d;
        var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
        this._current = interpolate(0);
        return function(t) {
            var d2 = interpolate(t);
            var pos = outerArc.centroid(d2);

            pos[0] = _radius * (midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? 0.90 : -0.90);
            return "translate(" + pos + ")";
        };
    })
    .styleTween("text-anchor", function(d) {
        this._current = this._current || d;
        var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
        this._current = interpolate(0);
        return function(t) {
            var d2 = interpolate(t);
            return midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? "start" : "end";
        };
    })
    .text(function(d) {
        if (d.endAngle - d.startAngle < 8.2 * Math.PI / 180) {
            return ""
        }
        return (d.data.NAME + ": " + d.data.amount);
    })
    ;
```

Comment: Why are you "re-applying" the font-weight style in your transition?  What selection does the `text` variable hold?  My guess is that it's the `tspan`.

Comment: @Mark well even without the reapplication of the font-weight I still need the final `.text(` to make some of the labels hidden - and this final step seems to make all the text a single weight